# Asynchronous loading of image in UICollectionViewCell causes labels to disappear

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uiimageview, uicollectionviewcell

I’m working on a photo gallery app that consists essentially of a navigation controller on to which is loaded instances of a collection view. Each of the collection view cells contains a UIImageView, and a label for the name of the image. The cells load the images in asynchronously.

This all works fine the first time each of the collection views are loaded, but if you step back to a previous collection view and forward again the labels disappear.

I think it must have something to do with loading the images asynchronously, as if I remove the image load the labels are fine, have the correct text and don’t disappear.

I’m not sure where I’m going wrong with the image loading...

The various components are:

Images are loaded using this extension method:

```
extension UIImageView {
public func imageFromServerURL(url: URL) {

    if ImageData.realPhotoCache.keys.contains(url.absoluteString){
        self.image = ImageData.realPhotoCache[url.absoluteString];
    }else{


        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in

            if error != nil {
                print(error)
                return
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
                let image = UIImage(data: data!)
                ImageData.realPhotoCache[url.absoluteString] = image;
                self.image = image
            })

        }).resume()
    }
}}
```

And the cells for the collection view are contucted like this:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    var cell: UICollectionViewCell;

    cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: photoCellReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath);

    let imageProvider = self.imageProviderForIndexPath(indexPath: indexPath);
    (cell as! tsPhotoCollectionViewCell).photoView.imageFromServerURL(url: imageProvider.GetThumbImageUrl());
    (cell as! tsPhotoCollectionViewCell).titleLabel.text = imageProvider.GetImageTitle()!;

    return cell
}
```

with the collection view being reset when it is returned to like so:

```
 func reset(){
    photoProviders = [ImageDataProvider]();
    self.collectionView?.reloadSections(IndexSet(integer: 0))
    startLoad()
}


override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    if(hasNavigatedAway){
        hasNavigatedAway = false;
        self.reset();
    }
}
```

The first load of a collection will generally be fine (cells in green, labels in red):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMc0s.jpg

but on naving away and coming back to a collection view, the labels are gone:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xO5w.jpg

The labels also seem to come and go with scrolling sometimes. I've tried everything I can think of, but haven't had any luck..

Comment: How do you layout your image views and labels? Do you use dynamic cell sizes? Besides, your async image loading has potential bug – as you know, cells are reused when you scroll the collection view, so lets say your image view is loading a huge image and while it does so you scroll the collection and that assigns new image URL to the cell which is loaded faster that previous one. After that the first image is downloaded and overrides the second one.

Comment: Could you check if `imageProvider.GetImageTitle()!` returns non-empty string?

Comment: @DanKarbayev the cells are defined in the main storyboard, and they use constraints to position the image and title label. Ye, the next step on the image loading is to add something to cancel the request, or check the it’s the right image to apply when the download is complete, would you recommend a particular approach?

Comment: @DanKarbayev i changed the cell creation to put `GetImageTitle()` into a variable and print it out, it definately contains the correct non empty string titles.

Comment: @HenryThomas try increasing UILabel's vertical content compression resistance priority

Comment: @Sh_Khan changing to `reloadData()` doesn't resolve the issue

Comment: @DanKarbayev setting the content compression resistance to 1000 looks like it's done the trick! Thats brilliant, thanks! Am I right in saying shifting that priority to 1000 (required) means that auto layout will compress other content instead of shrinking the label to a size that can't be seen?

Comment: Yes, auto layout engine will try to compress other views or to expand the parent view. BTW, do you mind if I write my comment in form of an answer and you accept it? (yay, internet points!)

Comment: @DanKarbayev ye go for it, was just about to suggest the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by your screenshots, it seems like UILabels are getting their heights compressed to 0 by expanded UIImageViews. Try increasing UILabel's vertical content compression resistance priority, say, to 1000, so that it becomes non-compressible (and, in turn, makes auto layout engine compress either UIImageView or spacings - depends on your constraints).